# How do I calculate the duration between 2 frames in an animation file

Tags: unity, animation

I want to find out the duration between 2 frames in animation file.

Is the following correct?

```
fDurationBetween2Frames = AnimationClip.length / AnimationClip.frameRate;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fDurationBetween2Frames = AnimationClip.length / NumberOfFrames;
```

Comment: Hi, I think you could include more info in your answer, e.g. how the result is meaningful in your application, or more details about what's going on in the sample code.